# If I spend Exp. Levels for stat boosts does my experience gain return to my new levels requirements?

Tags: one-way-heroics

There are Goddess Statues spread throughout the game that you can spend levels to gain stat boosts. If I spend a level does the game treat me like I had never earned it and grant me experience points based on that number or is there some other metric that determines how much things are worth?

For example (fake numbers):
* At Level 1 a Feral Dog gives 20% exp.
* At Level 7 it gives 3% Exp.
* If I am Level 7 and spend 6 levels to get 3 stat boosts and get back to Level 1 are Feral Dogs worth 20% exp again?